# How to add more than two textview in map infowindow in Google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

In may application am using Google map version 2.In that am customized map infowindow.Have to use only two text views.how can i add the more than two text view or rating bar in that infowindow.

**My coding**

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

    private final View myContentsView;

MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name));
tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.address));
tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

 return myContentsView;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

}
```

I don't know how to do.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `R.layout.info_window` can have as many `TextView`s as you want. You are not limited to two.

Comment: in marker am able to add more than two values only. `marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locLatLng).title(all_resturant.get(i).get("Restaurant name")).snippet(all_resturant.get(i).get("Address")));` how can i add the details for more text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `Marker` using `addMarker()`, you can retrieve the marker's ID via `getId()`. You can use that ID as the key to a `HashMap` or similar data structure, where you hold additional data to be associated with that `Marker`.

Or, do not put `all_resturant.get(i).get("Address"))` in your `snippet()`. Instead, put some lookup key in your `snippet()`, that you can use to look up your data, instead of using the marker ID.

Comment: i didn't understand clearly.please give some simple example to understand clearly.

Comment: @Yugesh: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Models and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/ImagePopups demonstrate these techniques.